# Can't Connect To NodeJS WS Server on Google Cloud Compute Engine

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, google-compute-engine

I have created two JavaScript files (a server file and a client file) that make up a small multiplayer game. When I run the server file locally using `node server.js` it starts running. I can then run the client file with `node client.js` to play the game, and everything works fine. However, when I try to host the game live on a linux instance (compute engine on google cloud) I am unable to connect to it from the clients. I am using the [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library for websockets in nodeJS.

Here is the code:

server.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const util = require('util');

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8889 });

var magicNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
var champion = "James";
var connections = [];

console.log('server listening...');

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

    connections.push({
        ws: ws,
        name: "",
        score: 0
    });

    ws.on('message', function incoming(message, flags) {

        var currentPlayer;

        for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
            if (connections[i].ws === ws) {
                currentPlayer = connections[i];
            }
        }

        var response;
        var obj = JSON.parse(message);

        if (parseInt(obj.guess) === magicNum) {

            currentPlayer.score++;
            response = "HOLY COW! YOU GUESSED THE MAGIC NUMBER!!!" +
                "I now declare you, " + obj.name + ", the new champion! (You have correctly guessed ( "
                + currentPlayer.score + " ) numbers)";
            champion = obj.name;
            magicNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);

            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ response: response, prompt: true }));

            for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
                if (connections[i].ws !== ws) {
                    response = "Uh oh, too slow! " + obj.name + " correctly guessed the number and is the new champion"
                        + " with " + currentPlayer.score + " correct guesses!";
                    connections[i].ws.send(JSON.stringify({ response: response, prompt: false }))
                }
            }

        } else {
            response = "Sorry, that's not the magic number. The champion is still " + champion + ".";
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({ response: response, prompt: true }));
        }

    });

    ws.on('close', function (a, b) {

        for (var i = 0; i < connections.length; i++) {
            if (connections[i].ws === ws) {
                connections.pop(i);
                console.log('removing connection from array');
            }
        }
        console.log('current connections now: ' + connections.length);
    })
});
```

client.js

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
var prompt = require('prompt');

//const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8889');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://35.185.74.130:8889');

var clientName = '';

function beginPromptForGuess() {

    var numberSchema = {
        properties: {
            number: {
                description: 'Please guess an integer between 1 and 20',
                pattern: /^\d+$/,
                message: 'please enter an integer.',
                required: true
            }
        }
    };

    console.log('prompt is: ' + prompt.stopped + " " + !prompt.started)

    if (prompt.stopped || !prompt.started) {
        console.log('starting prompt');

        prompt.get(numberSchema, function (err, result) {
            if (result) {
                console.log('got number');
                ws.send(JSON.stringify({ name: clientName, guess: result.number }));

            }
        })
    }
}

ws.on('open', function open() {

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Hey, let\'s play a game!');

        var nameSchema = {
            properties: {
                name: {
                    description: 'First, what is your name?',
                    pattern: /^[a-zA-Z\s\-]+$/,
                    message: 'Name must be only letters, spaces, or dashes',
                    required: true
                }
            }
        };

        prompt.get(nameSchema, function (err, result) {
            if (result) {
                clientName = result.name;
                console.log('Hi there, ' + result.name + '!');
                console.log('Let\'s play!');
                beginPromptForGuess();
            }
        });
    }, 500);

});

ws.on('message', function incoming(data, flags) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log('Server says: ' + obj.response);

    if (obj.prompt) {
        beginPromptForGuess();
    }
});
```

After I created the linux instance and used the SSH "Open in browser window" option to open a shell inside of my instance in the directory home/mrjim. The instance already had node so I pasted the server code into a file, ran `npm init` to create a package.json file, installed the ws library. Then I ran `node server.js` and it seems to be working:

[image]

However, when I try to connect to it from the client the shell hangs for a while and give this output:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.185.74.130:80
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1085:14)
```

Am I doing something wrong with the location of the server files or how I am writing the ip / ports? Thanks.

Also, here are my Google cloud configurations for the linux instance:
[image]

I have also opened ports in the firewall rules, but I still cannot connect from the client:

[image]

Comment: looks like your ip range is your internal ip. Find your public ip address. ( you can check this by typing "what's my ip" in chrome tab. ) add this in your IP range. Else, allow all request by providing your ip as 0.0.0.0/0 . it worked for me. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

In the screenshot of your google cloud settings it looks like you have the external ip set as **Ephemeral**. To access it from external clients (such as your local computer's command shell) you should change this to a statistic ip. Also, for the backend of a multiplayer game I would recommend using the much more secure SSL port 443 instead of 8889.

Good luck!